# Monkeypatching class method in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, monkeypatching

I have module named `square.py`:

```
import math

class Square(object):
    def __init__(radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def calculate_area(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.radius) * math.pi
```

And I have written test for this using `py.test`:

```
from square import Square


def test_mocking_class_methods(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('test_class_pytest.Square.calculate_area', lambda: 1)
    assert Square.calculate_area() ==  1
```

Running this test in python 2 gives me the following output:

```
>       assert Square.calculate_area() ==  1
E       TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with Square instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

But the same test in python 3 passes. Do you know why is that and how can I fix this test to work with python 2?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `calculate_area()` on an instane, but you called it on the `Square` class. You never created a square to calculate the area of.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 ensures that a method on a class is always called with the first argument being an instance of that class (Usually called `self`).

So, it is expecting something like this:

```
Square().calculate_area()
# Whih is equivalent to
Square.calculate_area(Square())
```

But this will also throw an error, as it is an unexpected argument (`TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)`)

To prevent checking for the `self` parameter, use the [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('test_class_pytest.Square.calculate_area', staticmethod(lambda: 1))
```